# Dynamically adding resource strings

Tags: c#

Is it possible to dynamically add resource strings on the fly to resource files? What if the effort involves multiple languages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the resourceWriter class on the MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.aspx

This class will perform all of the heavy lifting in terms of file I/O and data formatting.  There is also a great tutorial on how to actually use it at:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/105232008045338AM/1.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Resource files are compiled binaries (technically they're assemblies, but they contain no executable code), and the ResourceManager that works with these resource files is thus read-only.

What you can do is define a separate config file, referenced from the app.config, that contains installation-specific data as a custom ConfigurationSection, or simply as AppSettings. You can then use ConfigurationManager to load, read, *and write* these strings.