# Updating the existing DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Items collection

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

We have `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in which we have four values which are fixed. During run-time when the event `dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing` occurs we are trying to append new items to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                                             DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
   if (combo != null)
   {
      combo.DropDown += new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_DropDown);
   }
}

private void ComboBox1_DropDown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
   if (comboBox.Items != null)
   {
      List<String> elementname = Elements();
      foreach (string s in elementname)
      {
         if (!comboBox.Items.Contains(s))
         {
            comboBox.Items.Add(s);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting this exception :

[image]

Can you please suggest how to add the values to the existing `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in `Items` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding into the `Items` of editing control but not into the `Items` of the `ComboBoxColumn`, which will eventually be used for validation.

To get easy access to the hosting DGV we use the special type `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`. 
Now we will add the new choices to both `Items` collections now in the `ComboBox1_DropDown` event: :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)sender;
DataGridView dgv = comboBox.EditingControlDataGridView; 
if (comboBox.Items != null && dgv != null)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dcbc =
        (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) dgv.Columns[dgv .CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];

    List<String> elementname = Elements.ToList();
    foreach (string s in elementname)
    {
        if (!comboBox.Items.Contains(s))
        {
          comboBox.Items.Add(s);
          dcbc.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:

The new `Items` will not be **persistet** unless you code for it.

So if you have set fields to new values and saved them, you must also save and reload those new values before re-loading the DGV or else the values will not be in the `Column`'s list of values and throw the `DataError` again!

The usual place to store them would be a `DataTable` in your DBMS, but any other external storage may also be used like an `XML` file or maybe [dynamic resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034665/dynamically-adding-resource-strings) etc.. But the DBMS is the most natural choice imo.

Comment: I have tried the above solution provided by you but still I am getting the same error. DataGridViewComboBox Cell value is not valid

Comment: hm, here it made all the difference. When do you get the error? When dropping the first time or on a subsequent drop?

Comment: When I select the new item from the dropdown then I am getting that error

Comment: For 1st time the above code is working fine but if I reopen the same form again then its throwing the same error, since in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn items collection value is not added.

Comment: Well, the new Items will not be persistet unless you code for it. So if you have set fields to new values and saved them, you must also save and reload those new values! The usualy place to store them would be a DataTable but any other external storage may also be used like an XML file or maybe [dynamic resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034665/dynamically-adding-resource-strings) etc.. But The DBMS is the natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old thread, but I'll post my solution anyway. It can help someone else.
This example will update only a cell (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)

```
int rowIndex = dbGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
string test = dbGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
List<string> itemList = new List<string>{"one","two","three"};

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbbCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

cbbCell.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    cbbCell.Items.Add(item);
}
dbGrid["Column", rowIndex] = cbbCell;
```